Receive certain number of messages from Azure Service Bus queue via URL-request
does anybody know how to get a certain number of messages from a queue in Azure service bus via url without removing it?
https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/myqueue/messages?PeekMessages=true&NumberOfMessages=10&timeout=20&api-version=2013-08
via GET doesn't work. I just get only the first element in the queue.
I am able to read the messages from the the queue, but I don't want to loop(sending n GET-request for n messages) and I want to reduce network traffic.
Sending messages is possible(example: Chilkat), why not receiving?
Best case scenario: Sending a url with number of messages as parameter, receiving an json-array.
I have to use this method, because I have to work with an old C++ codebase(<C++11), so I have to use POST/GET/DELETE/PUT requests.

PeekMessages=true&NumberOfMessages=10&timeout=20&api-version=2013-08

try above cmd once

@Sampath with https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/myqueue/messages?PeekMessages=true&NumberOfMessages=2&timeout=20&api-version=2013-08 I just get one message.
